# Windows 7 crashes after changing number of processors

Tags: windows-7, msconfig

I incorrectly changed the number of processors in msconfig to 4.... my system has an i5 dual core processor.  The original number was 1. My computer will not boot to safe mode.  It will run a startup repair utility, but will not fix my problem.  I can then view advanced options and get to a command prompt.  When checking "set" from this prompt (X:\sources\recovery\tools>set) it has a line that states the number of processors=4.  Is there a way to change this number back to 1?

Answer (score 4):

Go back to the advanced options in the Windows bootloader and select "Last Known Good Configuration."